# What's the purpose of question mark in the beginning of variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/advanced_login#code-login_create_user_instance has some example code

```
def create
    ?user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if ?user && ?user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        log_in ?user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(?user) : forget(?user)
        redirect_to ?user
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

However, I still cannot understand the purpose of `?user` here. It is not a typo, right?

Comment: It's just a typo. Should be `@user`.

Comment: @Aetherus no, it is not. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just before this example there is an intro to it:

> By filling in the missing elements in Listing 9.27 and Listing 9.28 (indicated with question marks `?` and `FILL_IN`), complete this improved test of the “remember me” checkbox.

It always makes sense **to read** tutorials, not to scan them with a broken eye.

Comment: Yes, I see this at the first place. Maybe English is not my first language. I cannot understand it very well. Can you help to address in more details? Thanks.

Comment: This is an exercise: you are supposed to substiture question marks etc. with what should appear there.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you, @mudasobwa